Whether the given PDE is hyperbolic or parabolic for given conditions...
Consider second order partial derivative $au_{xx}+bu_{xy}+au_{yy}=0$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, then which of the following is true?
(a) the partial differential equation is hyperbolic for $b\leq 2a$
(b)the partial differential equation is parabolic for $b\leq 2a$
(c)the partial differential equation is elliptic for $|b|< 2|a|$
(d)the partial differential equation is hyperbolic for $|b|< 2|a|$
For second order partial differential equation of form, $R(x, y)u_{xx} + S(x,y)u_{xy} + T(x, y)u_{yy} + g(x, y, ux, uy) = 0$, to check hyperbolic,elliptic, parabolic we check $S^2-4RT>0\ <0\ or\ =0$
Here $S=a,R=b,T=a$, so $S^2-4RT=b^2-4a^2$
For hyperbolic $b^2-4a^2 >0$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}b^2-4a^2&>0\\b^2&>4a^2\\b&>2a\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since option a, is exactly opposite, it is wrong.
Now for parabolic $b^2-4a^2=0$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}b^2-4a^2&=0\\b^2&=4a^2\\b&=2a\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
The option (b) includes $b<2a$ also, so it should not be  correct.
And for elliptic $b^2-4a^2<0$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}b^2-4a^2&<0\\b^2&<4a^2\\b&<2a\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
So I thing option (c) must be the correct one, but because of the modulus sign I am not getting it.
How to interpret the option (c) is correct..?
Thanks in advance!!

$b^2 < 4 a^2$ implies that $|b| < 2 |a|$, not that $b < 2 a$. Consider, e.g., $a = -1, b = 1$.
